# Sacar el primer nombre de cada caja-oficina SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas, tengo un pequeño problema a ver si me podéis ayudar.

Parto de la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT Caja, Oficina, DNI, NombreCompleto, Importe
FROM miTabla
WHERE Importe > 50 and Caja LIKE '0%'
```

Lo que me piden ahora es agruparlo de forma que coja el primer nombrecompleto de cada caja-oficina
La consulta devolvería esos tres campos: Caja/oficina/nombrecompleto(el primero)

Entonces lo que he hecho es:

```
SELECT Caja, Oficina, NombreCompleto
FROM(
     SELECT Caja, Oficina, DNI, NombreCompleto, Importe
     FROM movimientos
     WHERE Importe > 50 and Caja LIKE '0%') as miTabla
GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, NombreCompleto
```

Pero me saca todos los registros y sólo quiero el primero de cada caja y oficina alfabéticamente hablando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tu necesitas es la funcion agregada [Min()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_min.asp) Retorna el menor valor (el primero alfabéticamente hablando y empezando desde 0 si son caracteres), bajo las agrupaciones de `Caja` y `Oficina`, de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT Caja, Oficina, Min(NombreCompleto)
FROM movimientos
WHERE Importe > 50 and Caja LIKE '0%'
GROUP BY Caja, Oficina
```

Comment: Esto sí ha salido bien. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que ordenar por Nombre completo y decir que solo quieres un registro. En SQL server debería ser algo así:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Caja, Oficina, NombreCompleto
FROM(
     SELECT Caja, Oficina, DNI, NombreCompleto, Importe
     FROM movimientos
     WHERE Importe > 50 and Caja LIKE '0%') as miTabla
GROUP BY Caja, Oficina, NombreCompleto
ORDER BY NomberCompleto ASC
```

Comment: Pues justo me da error de Sintaxis incorrecta en LIMIT

Comment: No se puede usar LIMIT con ORDER BY, tendrás que crear otra query respecto a esa tabla. He actualizado la query. Lo estoy haciendo sin probar nada, prueba que está correcta.

Comment: Problema. La cláusula ORDER BY no es válida en vistas, funciones insertadas, tablas derivadas, subconsultas ni expresiones de tabla común, salvo que se especifique también TOP

Comment: ¿Qué bbdd estás usando? En principio en mysql deberías ser válido SELECT FROM ORDER BY LIMIT

Comment: Estoy con Microsoft SQL server

Comment: En SQL server no existe LIMIT creo, prueba con TOP 1

Comment: @F.bernal con el `TOP 1` solo retorna un registro a mostrar. Lo que quiere el OP es que retorne el primer nombre completo por cada caja.